# Firefox loads https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js once, but not a second time

Tags: domain-name-system, https, firefox

A web app I am building seems to be broken in Firefox. It loads ok the first time, but not the second.

I checked the console and I found I get an error message that says:

Loading failed for the  with source “https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js”.

I tried loading the URL https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js in another tab, and it loads ok the first time, but if I reload it I get a security error:

```
Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue
```

and when I hit advanced I see

```
Someone could be trying to impersonate the site and you should not continue.
[...]
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

and under view certificate:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized - most of the time it seems to come from `Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA fra-SG`.

Neither Chrome nor Safari seem to be affected.

Another weird symptom is that pictures on stackoverflow are all broken.

Same things happens with github.

I'm on a Mac - no proxy, as far as I can tell.

I appreciate any help - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is some kind of opendns/caching blocking going on.

Solved by setting security.enterprise_roots.enabled to true (via about:config) to configure Firefox to use OS Keychain for trusted root certificates store.

Found here: https://superuser.com/questions/621694/deploy-root-certificate-to-firefox-on-mac-os-x